# c() function is changing my values from string to numeric

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
Row Type1 Type2 Type3
1   Cat   Dog    0
2   0     Dog    0
3   Cat   0      Hamster
4   0     0      0
5   Cat   0      Hamster
```

What I would like to do is create a bar plot so that each column gets its own column on the bar plot but omit the "0" column:

```
plotData <- table(c(myData$Type1, myData$Type2, myData$Type3), exclude = "0")
    barplot(plotData,
            main = "Pets",
            xlab = "Pet Type",
            cex.names = 0.8,
            col = "#00DD00")
```

The problem is that when I use the c() function, it changes my values to either 1s or 2s.
Example:

```
c(myData$Type1, myData$Type2, myData$Type3)
```

will print:

```
2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2
```

My desired result:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miV8A.png)

Comment: Your `Type*` columns are likely factor columns. And since `c()` drops attributes (like `levels` and `class`), you get the underlying integer value of the factor in return.

Comment: Instead of listing individual columns in `c()`, you may `unlist` relevant columns (e.g. all except the first): `barplot(table(unlist(d[ , -1]), exclude = "0"))`

Comment: @RichScriven Thank you, your answer helped me figure out a solution which I will post now.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Rich Scriven's comments, c() drops attributes which was the problem.
Listing and unlisting values helped me solve the problem.

```
plotData <- table(unlist(
          list(
            myData$Type1, 
            myData$Type2
            myData$Type3
          )
        ), exclude = "0")
        barplot(
          plotData,
          main = "My Data",
          xlab = "Pets",
          cex.names = 0.8,
          col = "#00DD00"
        )
```

Comment: Just unlist your data frame (which _is_ a list): `unlist(myData, -1])`